# Security reason url parts hiding?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big security problem with my program, and I need to make parts of my URL's hidden. I have searched on the net for a solution, with no luck. In my program I have admin and user accounts - the program is simply a database for workers dosie. Admins can see all dosies but the other users can only see dosies that are in their work group. So my problem is, when a user comes to see the dosie, the URL to access the information looks like this: "viewdosje.php?album=108. The problem being that the user can simply change album id and he can see other dosies, which is not good. For example:

```
"viewdosje.php?album=109"
```

By changing the number in the URL he can see other dosies. It would be great to hide that part of URL, or am I wrong? Please help me with an idea of some kind. I don't know where to start.

Comment: security through obscurity is like no security..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not hide the url, but validate the access to the resource in the application instead. When you receive the ID, before displaying content, perform a DB query to see if the current logged in user has access to that resource or not.

Comment: @Darhazer yea I that sou, no easy way to secure the data then that you have written. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Relying on "hiding" URLs is a terrible solution - anyone who can get access to the URL can get access to your private data. URLs can be accessed in all sorts of ways - sniffing web traffic (e.g. at insecure WIFI points), through JavaScript, through guessing, through getting access to browser history, and through all kinds of even scarier routes like trojans, keyboard loggers etc.

If the data in these employee records is sensitive/private, in most countries you are legally obliged to protect it adequately; even if there's no legal requirement, your company probably wants to avoid putting everyone's salary into the public domain.

The correct solution is to design a login mechanism, and assign user rights; when a user tries to access a page to which they don't have access, you send them an appropriate error message. There are numerous solutions for this in PHP - PEAR has a good implementation.

Answer (score -3):

I've no real experience with PHP so I can't help there, but if I was tackling this problem with JSP, or Rails I might do the following:

Perhaps store user identifiable information in a cookie, once authenticated, compare this information to the user database ? Prevent the page being served to unauthorised users if they manually edit the url.